# Windows 10 is not updating Open With setting in file properties

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I'm trying to simply change the default application for .txt files in Windows 10 Pro (version 1803, build 17134.376).

I tried file properties and selecting the application. I can select the application but the default application value doesn't change.

I also tried going through the default application settings under Apps & Features -> Default Apps. That doesn't seem to allow for browsing to an application.

Are other's experiencing this issue as well?

Comment: This is a known bug in 1803

Comment: Is there a work around?

Comment: @JoshRusso because lots of people are asking this question, we are pointing all of them to the one instance of this question, answering all questions we have answers to there, and closing the others. This allows us to have a single place with all the information we have. Note, it does NOT mean we'll have answers to every question YOU have, but it does mean we won't have to keep repeating ourselves and risk some information showing up one place and not another.

Comment: @music2myear I completely understand. The question that Ramhound referenced was exactly what I was looking for.